# How to build AIC model selection table using mlogit models

Tags: r, mlogit, log-likelihood

I'm trying to build an AIC table for my candidate set of models in R, which were run using `mlogit`. I've used `glm` and `glmer` in the past, and have always used the package `AICcmodavg` and `aictab` to extract values and create a model selection table. This package doesn't seem to work for `mlogit`, so I'm wondering if there are any other ways of creating an AIC table in R besides manual calculation using the log-likelihood value?

Example of mlogit model output:

```
Call:
mlogit(formula = Case ~ Dist_boulder + Mesohabitat + Depth + 
    Size + Size^2 | -1, data = reach.dc, method = "nr")

Frequencies of alternatives:
0 1 2 3 
1 0 0 0 

nr method
5 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 1.19E-05 
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
                   Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)  
Dist_boulder      -0.052165   0.162047 -0.3219  0.74752  
Mesohabitatriffle -1.400752   0.612329 -2.2876  0.02216 *
Mesohabitatrun     0.302697   0.420181  0.7204  0.47128  
Depth              0.137524   0.162521  0.8462  0.39745  
Size               0.336949   0.145036  2.3232  0.02017 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -86.627
```

### example of models run (from my candidate set of 14)

```
 predation.reach<-mlogit(Case ~ Dist_boulder + Mesohabitat + Depth + Size + Size^2 | -1, data=reach.dc)
velocity.reach<-mlogit(Case ~ Mid_vel | -1, data=reach.dc)
spaces.reach<-mlogit(Case~ Embedded + Class | -1, data=reach.dc)
substrate.reach<-mlogit(Case ~ Class | -1, data=reach.dc)
```

### defining candidate set list

```
cand.set.reach<-list(predation.reach, velocity.reach, spaces.reach, substrate.reach)
```

Comment: `broom::augment()` will be the way to go, but not yet ... https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/192  Does `bbmle::AICtab()` work ... ?

Answer (score 2):

`bbmle::AICtab()` appears to work.

```
library("mlogit")
m1 <- mlogit(formula = mode ~ price + catch | income,
  data = Fish,     
  alt.subset = c("charter", "pier", "beach"), method = "nr")
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . - price)
bbmle::AICtab(m1,m2)
##    dAIC  df
## m1   0.0 6 
## m2 412.1 5
```

By default `bbmle::AICtab()` gives only delta-AIC and the model degrees of freedom/number of parameters, but you can use optional arguments to get the absolute AIC, AIC weights, etc..

It also works with a list:

```
L <- list(m1,m2)
bbmle::AICtab(L)
```

In the tidyverse world,

```
library(broom)
L %>% purrr::map(augment) %>% bind_rows()
```

ought to work, but [doesn't yet](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/192).